# P congruent to F, where $ F $ is the fermat point

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

[image]

The $ P $ point moves from $ B $ to $ C $ in the $ BC $ arc of the $ ABC $ circle where $ x = AP , y = BP, z = CP $. Create an elegant construction from the $ P $ point where $ x + y + z $ is maximum

Attemp: Fixing points A, B and C,
we have to slide P over the arc BC its greatest sum occurs when P≡F,
where F is Fermat's point.
Note the following:
As P approaches B, the y side decreases and z increases, but when P≡B x + y + z does not reach its maximum and the same occurs
for when P≡C or is very close to C.
It follows that we must have P to be the midpoint of the arc BC, so x + y + z would reach its maximum value.
Then we will consider a point D outside the circumference such that ΔBDC is equilateral, so DB and DC are tangent to the circumference.
As P is the midpoint of the arc BC, it follows that P≡F and so we have <PCB = <PBC = 30 °.

I'am right?

Comment: It seems you have some confusion regarding [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point). Fermat point *minimizes* the sum, you're looking for a $P$ that *maximizes*. Fermat point lies either inside or on the triangle but here $P$ is constrained to the circumcircle (outside of the triangle). Nonetheless, great problem! [+1]